# VIM / GVFS / Unwanted access right alteration on save

Tags: vim, gvfs

I'm using Vim under GNU/Linux and I use the gnome functionalities to mount FTP / SFTP as drives using GVFS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS).

When **I use Vim to edit files** directly on the GVFS folders I have the following problem : **file's access rights are altered**.

Before :

```
-rwxrwxrwx
```

After `:w` :

```
-rwx------
```

When I use Gedit I have not this problem, so I suppose the problem is not directly from GVFS.

Is there something in my `.vimrc` that I can add to prevent those alterations ?

Comment: Martin, are you using FTP or SFTP? Those are completely different protocols.

Comment: I mainly use SFTP, but I have, some times, to use FTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem a few months ago, eating up a whole site just by editing 3 files. Thankfully, the problem was easy to fix and I didn't explore the whys and hows and vowed to never use that feature again.

But your question lead me to [this thread on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/227808) that you may find interesting. In short:

- The bug is on GVFS's side and has been around since forever without any progress.
- It happens with other editors/IDEs, too.
- There's nothing you can do in Vim itself to prevent that bug.
- Using `sshfs` instead of GVFS seems to work correctly.

Comment: It looks like it is a good solution. I just need a simple way to mount those sftp (I found something interesting here Fusauto ( http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/fusauto )[FRENCH]. Thanks

Comment: Bookmarked. Merci.

Answer (score 0):

Experiment with [`'backup'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'backup'), [`'backupcopy'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'backupcopy') and [`'writebackup'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'writebackup') options. This might have something to do with the way Vim creates backup files – in some modes, it renames the original and creates a new file in its place, possibly causing Gvfs to do the same on the server.